# mongoose how to update an user profile with id

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I created an simple CRUD operation in nodejs and mongoose. Updating an user using RESTAPI.
an error message in Insomnia

```
Error: Server returned nothing (no headers, no data)
```

URL

> http://localhost:1337/api/users/update/63ab9b716065482273e58b75

@PUT METHOD

router.put("/update/:id",updateUser)

```js
const updateUser = async (req,res,next) => {
  if (req.params.id === req.user.id) {
    try {
      const updateuser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
        $set:req.body,
      })
      res.status(200).json(updateuser)
    } catch (error) {
      next(error)
    }
  }
}
```

how to updating with id of user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`req.params.id` will be of type string, while `req.user.id` will be probably of type ObjectId.

Can you try this:

```js
if (req.params.id.toString() === req.user.id.toString()) {
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before req.user.id type is ObjectId. Also you should send an error when ids are not the same.

Example for your code:

```
const updateUser = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    if (req.params.id !== req.user.id.toString()) {
      // Send error in here.
    }

    const updateuser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
      $set: req.body,
    });
    res.status(200).json(updateuser);
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
};
```